# Cleared Code Coverage cache

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests, cache

How can I clear the code coverage and I'm stuck to 60% and regardless its not what test I write its not increasing but my question is: is there a way to flush the cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clear your coverage in Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution > View Test History > Clear Test Data. Afterwards, you can go to Setup > Develop > Apex Classes, and choose Run All Tests to regenerate your coverage.

Answer (score 0):

The other way I found is just going to this url and will take you what sfdcfox talking about: hope this will help others.

Make sure you change XYZ with whatever Salesforce instance

```
https://XYZ.salesforce.com/07M
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reverse engineer the API calls Salesforce executes when you clear the test data using the developer console. The following piece of codes makes the same API calls (this piece of code is an SFDX plugin and therefor written in typescript):

```
await initializeUx();
logInfo(ux, 'Remove any existing code coverage data from the target org to create a clean coverage report...');

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
const orgDisplayResponse: OrgDisplayResponse = await runCommand2JSON(
    `sfdx org display ${target ? '-o ' + target : ''} --json`,
    { silently: !settings.isVerbose }
);

if (orgDisplayResponse.status !== 0) {
    return;
}

// Get csrf token.
const parameters = {
    '-d': '-d "action=GET_OPTIONS"',
    '-X': '-X POST',
    '-b': `-b 'sid=${orgDisplayResponse.result.accessToken}'`,
    '-H': `-H 'Authorization: Bearer ${orgDisplayResponse.result.accessToken}'`,
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
const response: string = await runCommandWithResponse(
    `curl ${orgDisplayResponse.result.instanceUrl}/_ui/common/apex/test/ApexTestQueueServlet ${Object.values(parameters).join(
        ' '
    )}`,
    { silently: !settings.isVerbose }
);

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
const responseInJson: TestQueueOptionsResponse = JSON.parse(response.replace('while(1);', ''));

// Clear test code coverage.
parameters['-d'] = `-d 'action=CLEAR_TEST_RESULTS&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=${responseInJson._csrf}'`; // eslint-disable-line no-underscore-dangle

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
await runCommand(
    `curl ${orgDisplayResponse.result.instanceUrl}/_ui/common/apex/test/ApexTestQueueServlet ${Object.values(parameters).join(
        ' '
    )}`,
    { silently: !settings.isVerbose }
);
```

Hopefully this is hopeful for you.

Take note, you need to include a cookie in the callouts with your access token defined in a 'sid' property. Furthermore, the run commands method simply execute a terminal command.